# Black screen with Screen Sharing and VMWare

Tags: mac, vmware, screen-sharing

I've just upgrade my iMac to Catalina and the security update for Catalina. I'm at 10.15.7. While I start by describing a VMWare issue, I think this is a bigger issue and it makes Screen Sharing unusable, too.

Earlier today I wanted to use VMWare for a Linux based VM. When the window opened, I could see the screenshot of the image of the suspended machine. Once it started running, I got a black screen with a pointer I could move. I paused it and could see the image again. I tested several times and the pattern remained: Pause it, I can see it. Activate it and it's black.

I thought, "Okay, haven't used that in a while, maybe there are updates I need for Catalina," and went on to another task and started to update my MacMini, in another building, by installing the latest security update for Catalina. It started downloading and next time I came back, the screen on the screen share was black - but the pointer is there.  Due to back issues, walking to the building and hooking up the MacMini to the monitor will have to wait until later. But if the box were down, Screen Sharing wouldn't connect at all.

So, again, I moved to the next task: finishing a few tasks on a Debian Linux system running KDE (late versions, probably the latest at this point). I've been using KRFB on there for a while with good success. I clicked to run Screen Sharing and see the Linux system. It won't connect. (I can ssh to the Debian box, though.)

I don't know if this is the same issue, but it seems like there's something wrong with software trying to do any kind of screen sharing at all. I've rebooted and the issues are still there. It seems that whenever I'm looking at a screen being emulated or shared, I get just black.

What's going on and what can I do to troubleshoot or fix this?

Comment: There is a support article on VMware Customer Connect that could apply to your issue: https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/79989 Could you follow the steps and report back?

Comment: I did that yesterday - and VMWare never showed up as an app in that list, so I couldn't give it any permissions. I also gave them feedback and asked which versions of their software that works for.

Comment: Thank you for checking. The document applies to VMware Fusion 11.x. What is your VMware Fusion version? If VMware Fusion is not listed in System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Screen Recording, you can add it yourself by pressing the + button (you may need to unlock the pane by clicking the lock and authenticating).

Comment: My version is still in the 10.x range. I found the version info on that page - over to the side where most sites are posting links to related info or other important pages - a non-obvious place. Maybe I need to upgrade. I use it just often enough to need Fusion.